# sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: carrito.Nombre

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Tengo el error `sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: carrito.Nombre` al querer guardar unos datos ingresados por el usuario en una tabla, pero en ningun momento pido un dato Nombre

```
def agregarCarro():
    def alCarro(id, cantidad):
        # Obtener los resultados del formulario y meterlos en una base de datos
        query = 'INSERT INTO carrito(idProducto, Nombre, Precio) SELECT idProducto, Nombre, Precio FROM Productos WHERE idProducto = ?'
        parametros = (idInput.get(), )
        run_query(query, parametros)
        query2 = 'INSERT INTO carrito (Cantidad) VALUES (?)'
        parametros2 = (cantidadInput.get(), )
        run_query(query2, parametros2)
        
    f6 = Toplevel()
    root.title("Agregar productos")

    Label(f6, text="Rellene el formulario del pedido.", font=('Arial', 15, tkFont.BOLD)).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=5, ipadx=10)
    Label(f6, text="Id del producto seleccionado: ").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)
    idInput = Entry(f6)
    idInput.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    Label(f6, text="Cantidad que desea comprar: "). grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5)
    cantidadInput = Spinbox(f6, from_=1, to=100, width=10)
    cantidadInput.grid(row=2, column=1)
    Button(f6, text="Agregar", bg='#62DD6E', fg='white', font=('Arial', 10, tkFont.BOLD), command=lambda:[alCarro(idInput.get(), cantidadInput.get())]).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)
    Button(f6, text="Listo", bg='#62DD6E', fg='white', font=('Arial', 10, tkFont.BOLD), command=lambda:[f6.destroy()]).grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5)
```

Estoy intentando pasar los datos de una tabla a otra segun un input del usuario, el cual debe especificar el id del producto y la cantidad que va a comprar. Elegir el id y pasarlo a la otra tabla funciona bien pero el problema viene al querer seleccionar la cantidad, alguna idea de como solucionarlo o hacerlo mejor?

Comment: Sin var las definiciones de las tablas es dificil decir a ciencia ciera que puede estar pasando, aunque lo que supongo es que la tabla `Productos` permite valores nulos su la columna `Nombre` mientras que la tabla `carrito` no permite nulos para su columna `Nombre`. Revise si la fila de la tabla [ producto` con la que se esta realizando la prueba tiene valor nulo en su columna `Nombre`

Comment: Ambas tablas no permiten valores nulos en ningún dato, pero ahora que lo desactive la tabla `carrito` queda con valores mixtos y se borran los datos de la otra tabla, es raro explicar lo que pasa